# replacing spaces in java using replace or replaceAll

Tags: java

I'm working on a java project and I need to send a date format within a URL but the container of date send it with spaces which is impossible so i convert it to a string and I used the replace method to replace the spaces with "" or "-" but it didn't work

Here is the code:

```
Date date = date_debut.getDate();
String dateconver= date.toString();
String datef= dateconver.replace(" ", "");
```

And here is the error: incompatible types string can not be converted to char

I have tried also to use replaceAll but the IDE didn't even show it

Comment: maybe you just need to encode url parameters instead of this?

Comment: @Dali, you definitely need this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Date date = date_debut.getDate();
String dateconver= date.toString();
String datef= dateconver.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Comment: nop error illegal character \

Comment: add Log.d("Test","String: " + dateconver); after date.toString(); and paste the Logcat error

Comment: this will remove `\s` occurrences (not whitespaces). To regex-based replace, use `.replaceAll()`. Can't understand why this answer is upvoted, as even if properly used it will produce some wierd `MonMar2814:43:56AST2016`

Comment: Bad copy paste from duplicate question.

Comment: incompatible types !!!!
that's really weird 
many people used the same code and it worked , for me it didn't

Comment: I told you, I can't even find it , netbeans doesn't even show it replaceAll()

Comment: @DaliLandoulsi working fine at my end MonMar2817:23:12IST2016

Comment: This copy-paste doesn't answer the question. OP talks about replacing **spaces**. And what about the error OP receives?